# Why to use Spring provided JSTLView view resolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, jstl

While reading the spring reference specification i hit upon the following: "*When using the Java Standard Tag Library you must use a special view class, the JstlView, as JSTL needs some preparation before things such as the i18N features will work.*"

I am able to use JSTL in my spring application without configuring JSTLView as a view resolver. Given that, what is the disadvantage of not using the spring provided JSTLView resolver (apart from the i18N features the spec refers to)?

Could not find any explanation of the same in the spec in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am able to use JSTL in my spring application without configuring JSTLView as a view resolver

No, you application did use the `JSTLView` for view resolver if the [InternalResourceViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html#InternalResourceViewResolver%28%29) is set and JSTL library is present in classpath.

Comment: Okay. Then, what is the use of explicitly providing the viewClass property as specified in the reference spec?